# Reducing fractions

Tags: fractions

How can I get  [if it's possible]:
$$ 2- \frac{1}{n+1} $$
from this: 
$$2- \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} $$

**EDIT:**

I started like this:
$$2- \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}= 2-\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)} =2-\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)}  $$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I assume you wish to ask how to prove this equality?

$$2 - \frac 1 n + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer - yes

Comment: I would start from the term $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. Try to write it in a form
$$
\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \equiv \frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n+1}
$$
where $\equiv$ means that they are algebraically equivalent. Can you find $A$ and $B$ so that this is true? Of course we need to assume $n\neq 1$ and $n\neq 0$. Hint: multiply both sides of the equation by $n(n+1)$.

Comment: I'd forget the $2$s and put $$-\frac1n+\frac1{n(n+1)}$$ over a common denominator.

Comment: A common trick is $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{(n+1)-n}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$ Similarly, one has $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac12 \frac{(n+2) - n}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac12\left[\frac{1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right]$$ This sort is trick is pretty useful when you turn a sum into a telescoping one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I started like this: $$2- \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=
>  2-\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)} =2-\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)}  $$

The mistake happened here:

$$2-\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)} =2-\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)}$$

because you forgot the minus sign. You can rewrite the left hand side as

$$2 +\frac{-n-1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ and continue from there.

Comment: I started the same way and came to : n+2/n(n+1). Then I got stuck. That's why I thought it might be a different way to start. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: @HodayaShalom You shouldn't get $n+1$ in the numerator. You probably forgot the minus sign in front of $\frac1n$.

Comment: magnificent. That was the problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to care about the term $2$, it suffices to establish

$$\frac1{n+1}=\frac1n-\frac1{n(n+1)}.$$

If you multiply by $n(n+1)$, this is

$$n=n+1-1.$$